# Can I use the IF function for an Multiple select, and point to the same colum

Tags: spreadsheet

I have two colums with data.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Text 1 |
| Cell 2 | Text 2 |

In a diffrent Sheet, i have a select to pick from the Column A
If the select is = to Cell1, I want to add to the next cell Text 1, If the select is = to Cell5 to add the text from ColumnB: Text 5

I have something like this now:

```
IF(I2=FORMULAS!$A$10,FORMULAS!$B$10,IF(I2=FORMULAS!$A$11,FORMULAS!$B$11,IF(I2=FORMULAS!$A$12,FORMULAS!$B$12,"")))
```

And it works, but, in the Select (`FORMULAS!A10-A22`) there are a lot of rows, and i should put this for each of them